# Are games specific to a Wii console or the disk

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u

Are game saves specific to one wii console? For example if I I sold my wii and bought a wii u and played my old wii game on the wii u would the save be there of would I have to start the game again?

Comment: Save games are *never* stored to the disc, game discs are read-only.  I think there's a way to back up your saves to a memory card though, which you can then plug into your new wii.

Comment: So i would have to start all my games again unless I transferred to old saves with an sd card?

Comment: You'll need to do a system transfer first, even if you intend to use saves from an sd card. If you want to use saves from another Wii without doing a system transfer, you'll need to mod your console, but since this borders on piracy, we won't help you do that.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't realise you had to do a whole system transfer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Wii discs are read only, meaning no data are stored on them, only on the Wii itself. You'll need to copy your saves from your Wii to your Wii U through the [systems transfer process](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1124/~/how-to-transfer-content-from-a-wii-to-a-wii-u), and you'll need to have both systems at hand, so you cant sell your Wii before buying a Wii U.